# Excel Power Query - new data from a source file doesn't create a new row in the current table

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a source Excel worksheet [image 1]. This will change over time and the new data is not appended in the source file but inserted somewhere in the worksheet [image 3].

In another worksheet I am using power query to load the data from source.xlsx into a new table. This is used to add some additional data as new columns [image 2].

If I refresh the worksheet and additional data was inserted in the source.xlsx all data below the new entry is shifted down except the data in the new colums. Therfore the additional data is not in the correct row anymor [image 4]

Is there a way to append new rows to the bottom or create a new row for new data in the source file?

[image: sdsd]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We need to see the code that is generating the additional column

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the data you adding is organized.

Probably the easiest way is to add this data as xlookup. This way if you use column A as match criteria it will be always correct and matching regardless the sequence/order of values in column A.

In PowerQuery you can do similar with MERGE/JOIN.

In both cases you need a link/reference in the 2nd table where your additional data is, in order to have something to match with.

If you just want to make sure to have new entries at the bottom, adding an ID column with increasing number and sorting against it should do the trick.